# How to use Javascript to draw a new moving ball when I click?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, draw

I wanna get a new moving ball in random position when I click the canvas with mouse left button.

For example:
    When I click the canvas three times, I can get three ball moving on the canvas.

This question is from the Khan academy:

[My Code](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-more-mouse-interaction/5720325838159872)

```js
var positionX = 20;
var positionY = 20;
var speed;
var controlSpeed=5;
var randomNum=random(0,400);
var randomNum2=random(0,400);
//repeat
draw = function() {
    background(202, 255, 97);
    
    fill(66, 66, 66);
    positionX = positionX + speed;
    positionY = positionY + speed;
    //ellipse repeatDraw
    ellipse(positionX, 200, 50, 50);
    ellipse(200, positionY, 50, 50);
    
    //
    if (positionX > 375) {
        speed = -controlSpeed;
    }
    if (positionX < 25) {
        speed = controlSpeed;
    }
    if (positionY > 375) {
        speed = -controlSpeed;
    }
    if (positionY < 25) {
        speed = controlSpeed;
    }
    
};
```

Comment: Can you include your code *inside* the question using a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)?

Comment: I put a link: My code, the link can get my code, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I saw the link. Put here we expect the question itself to include all the necessary information.

Comment: OK I am newbie, thanks for you teaching me :)

Comment: I will try to learn how to use Stack snippet, wait me to read the articles@.@ I am from Taiwan. :)

Comment: I finished my snippet, but i can't put whole code into the snippet, it said too long @.@

Comment: @HolyDragonHolyDragon don't worry too much. I changed my answer to something that works in the site you linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
var balls = [];

//repeat
draw = function() {
    if (mouseIsPressed) {
        balls.push({x: random(0, 400), y: random(0, 400), vx: random(-10, 10), vy: random(-10, 10), r: 50});
    }
    
    background(202, 255, 97);
    fill(66, 66, 66);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        var ball = balls[i];
        ellipse(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, ball.r);
        ball.x += ball.vx;
        ball.y += ball.vy;
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, later  i will spend time to read. thanks :) I am eating lunch XD. Have a good day!

Comment: Cool this coding is too cool!!! I just press, a lot of ball appearing! thanks!

Comment: @HolyDragonHolyDragon If the answer solves your problems and you do not need any additional help, please consider accepting the answer. Thanks!